# Notification not triggered on Android Wear OS

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, wear-os

I am playing around with notifications on Wear OS and testing on a Fossil Falster 3 with Android API 28.

Why is the following notification not being triggered, in an standalone app.
The code is pretty much right from the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/notifications/creating).

```
    button_in.setOnClickListener {
        val notificationId = 1
        // The channel ID of the notification.
        val id = "my_channel_01"
        // Build intent for notification content
        val viewPendingIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).let { viewIntent ->
            PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, viewIntent, 0)
        }
        // Notification channel ID is ignored for Android 7.1.1
        // (API level 25) and lower.
        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, id)
            .setLocalOnly(true)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            .setContentTitle("TITLE")
            .setContentText("TEXT")
            .setContentIntent(viewPendingIntent)

        NotificationManagerCompat.from(this).apply {
            notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build())
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "button was pressed!")
    }
```

I can see the "button was pressed!" text, but I am not getting any notifications.

Comment: If you're in a standalone app running directly on a watch running API 28, then you need to create a notification channel. Where are you doing that?

Comment: Does the Android Wear app on your device have access to notifications? I.e. in 4.4, you can find this at `Settings -> Security -> Notification Access` - within the notification access screen, make sure Android Wear is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch apps require a notification channel, unlike Android apps which do not work like this.

In your code, `val notificationId = 1` refers to the notification channel ID.

You can construct a `NotificationChannel` and register it like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    // Create the NotificationChannel
    val name = getString(R.string.channel_name)
    val descriptionText = getString(R.string.channel_description)
    val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    val mChannel = NotificationChannel(1, name, importance) // 1 is the channel ID
    mChannel.description = descriptionText
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel)
}
```

Notice in the commented code, in `val mChannel = ...`, you can see that the first parameter value `1` refers to the channel ID, as specified in your code in the OP.

You can read more about notification channels here: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels